# InvalidFieldNameException in my findOneBy

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an error then

```
$resetPassword =$resetPasswordRepository->findOneBy(['token' => $request->token]);
```

error:

```
 InvalidFieldNameException
    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.token AS token_3, t0.created_at AS created_at_4 FROM reset_passwords t0 WHERE t0.token = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["EF5i4ooFh6ThHqDsSQKaEGzfIejpZvRaLP8Xtg0diTpEQEsl6buFRlHM7WfVZBzx"]:
    
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'field list'
```

in my controller

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    public function showForgetPasswordForm()
    {
        return view('auth.forgetPassword');
    }


    public function submitForgetPasswordForm(ForgetPasswordRequest $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request->validated();

        $reset_password = new ResetPassword();
        $reset_password->setEmail($request->email);
        $reset_password->setToken(Str::random(64));
        $reset_password->setCreated_at(Carbon::now());

        EntityManager::persist($reset_password);
        EntityManager::flush();
       //dd($reset_password->getToken());

     Mail::send('email.forgetPassword', ['token'=>$reset_password->getToken()], function($message) use($request){
            $message->to($request->email);
            $message->subject('Reset Password');

        });

        return back()->with('message', 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!');
    }

    public function showResetPasswordForm($token) {
        return view('auth.forgetPasswordLink', ['token' => $token]);
    }


    public function submitResetPasswordForm(SubmitResetPasswordRequest $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request->validated();
       //dd($request->validated());
       $resetPasswordRepository = EntityManager::getRepository(ResetPassword::class);
      // dd($resetPasswordRepository);
        $resetPassword =$resetPasswordRepository->findOneBy(['token' => $request->token]);
      //  dd($resetPassword);

       // $user = $repository->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);
       // $user = EntityManager::find(User::class, $userId);


       // EntityManager::flush();
        DB::table('reset_passwords')->where(['email'=> $request->email])->delete();

        return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Your password has been changed!');
    }
```

in  ResetPassword entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Faker\Provider\DateTime;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/**
 * ResetPassword entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="reset_passwords")
 */
class ResetPassword
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $token;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var DateTime|null
     */

    protected $created_at;

    //GettersSetters
    use GetterSetter;

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $token
     */
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;

    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;

    }

    /**
     * Set date.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created_at
     *
     * @return
     */
    public function setCreated_at($created_at)
    {
        $this->created_at = Carbon::now();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date.
     *
     * @return DateTime|null
     */
    public function getCreated_at()
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with Postgresql reserved words, in your case with the work ***token***. Here you can find a [list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Try to quote the column name like this

```
  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="`token`")
  */
  protected $token;
```